# can't login to a qemu ubuntu server machine using ssh

Tags: server, ssh, virtualization, cloud, qemu

I was following this tutorial : https://gist.github.com/george-hawkins/16ee37063213f348a17717a7007d2c79
except the machine is arm64. I created cloud.txt (observing the indentation carefully). The cloud.txt is below(modified for security).

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: ckim
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABASLKDjfoIBJLKJFikdsdslfkdjLBIlKDfjlIELfjpQOkcVLKjlkdfk6L7l3CypkhJQt+lPkpT5Rl9q4SVIUUgQmXEbuE11e5Gs9slkdfjlsdfsdgsdVt1HoZriRtgsyxweJx5HQLVvqY6lcPPXhJk/drIeceA8T04oohzWF3nquzaUJJkvOB4aI2i4dqTddN9iOS4c0c+Q4sLSogHRzib77y5T03x7wjvdn+M8LSDKjolIGIflkwjodfLDKjfoq*9023k4j98dkfw09etwerf807cTS2eJHIAkImccuuv/OsmVkTYetpAI86hX79yDMRr3CfS9Pw2g44a4+Cd9RR9K6LhlKhGltON1x/ ckim@etri.re.kr
    sudo: [ 'ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' ]
    group: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```

and ran this command.

> ../QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/build/aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 2     -m 1024     -M virt     -cpu cortex-a57     -bios QEMU_EFI.fd     -nographic     -device virtio-blk-device,drive=image -drive if=none,id=image,file=ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img     -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cloud     -drive if=none,id=cloud,file=cloud.img     -device virtio-net-device,netdev=user0     -netdev user,id=user0     -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22

The machine started installing ubuntu 16.04 and gave me login in prompt. As directed by the tutorial, in another terminal I did

> ssh -p 2222 ckim@etri.re.kr

I also tried ckim@localhost but it was declined. But there is no response(only time-out). In the virtual machine server side, I see this message printed(some parts modified for security reason).

```
Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS ubuntu ttyAMA0

ubuntu login: [  300.875061] cloud-init[1353]: Generating locales (this might take a while)...
[  333.541423] cloud-init[1353]:   en_US.UTF-8... done
[  333.576625] cloud-init[1353]: Generation complete.
[  349.423893] cloud-init[1353]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 20 May 2021 09:02:46 +0000. Up 291.35 seconds.
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Authorized keys from /home/ckim/.ssh/authorized_keys for user ckim++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
ci-info: | Keytype |                                       Fingerprint (sha256)                                      | Options |     Comment     |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
ci-info: | ssh-rsa | 70:b5:ac:33:ba:dd:64:f5:1c:6f:qq:01:43:5b:c6:34:78:72:pp:e6:9c:9a:0f:17:00:f7:2c:e8:ab:cd:8f:40 |    -    | ckim@etri.re.kr |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: 
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: #############################################################
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: 1024 SHA256:hVRxCzDQ3cxchelloJwLIYRhcubhydMV8dvMNq1vOIo root@ubuntu (DSA)
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: 256 SHA256:j1TorabbitinJqj5ZM/VkCilu6jTF3nyXYwMGkfBHSI root@ubuntu (ECDSA)
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: 256 SHA256:QuA9y3+rzRjwILxnVlWLgorillaIHQlZAiN2e6rBUuE root@ubuntu (ED25519)
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: 2048 SHA256:F7ljNGmouse5SOfBAM4/8MXNNS5Wbvv1gxNoRbzU3cI root@ubuntu (RSA)
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
<14>May 20 09:04:13 ec2: #############################################################
-----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFbPIwkb+TVfkxu4GGDf9bknQ2uxjDWhDjz2joP5u3ZoBapUEsXYanujLCNi13Opp0csvybtYZQ/POa91otZsEk= root@ubuntu
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIHjiCpRAufWW9B9dw+krdEndY0BKi1m9Qks4e4qMAeJD root@ubuntu
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsv1bcGVTy6s4tc6QeCZ50X/pv+v8h7EeezrrA7jWWnpHyb/Q3F7IO0helloJFZYL+QnTF9fH8A8gkPac+hbkJ2HXB9rgCK3vslkdfj8923oklskdjfLSKDjflSDf/sdofiuoi98wsldkjfslkdts56ILv4tYkkSgqviZMCJJUUyI2P9vEjMrAdARZCZQEqvokHT9dGbPVRa+lSa4i12345L4NeskRxySBt32b0hxvms1MzQePdroiEwawgeBjonSrUtx2zpIR8pGOTGATaG9I3Z73nYhzqdLIC//WKRZqetcTaTG9B5q6S0l2k+F9wkAG+Jib7HNjD2oXIFFCAY2hFcVW7/9HPoWnmF3b root@ubuntu
-----END SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
[  380.272694] cloud-init[1400]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 20 May 2021 09:04:05 +0000. Up 369.55 seconds.
[  380.282847] cloud-init[1400]: Cloud-init v. 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 finished at Thu, 20 May 2021 09:04:15 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/vda][dsmode=net].  Up 379.81 seconds

Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS ubuntu ttyAMA0

ubuntu login: ckim
Password:
```

So even though I installed ubuntu server on qemu virtual machine, I can't log in . Could anyone find anything wrong here. Any suggestion or information on how to login will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also cannot login to Ubuntu cloud image 20.04 qemu instance

Answer (score 0):

according to your qemu command you mapped the host port 5022 to the guest port 22, see `hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22`.

So therefor your ssh command should be `ssh -p 5022 ckim@localhost`.

Peace

Comment: I tried `ssh -p 2222 ckim@localhost` it said 'connection refused'. When I tried `ssh -p 5022 ckim@localhost` is said `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` after a while.  I tried both with ckim@etri.re.kr (this one in the id_rsa.pub file) but no response (or time-out later? I quit waiting..) I'll try later from the beginning and see.